# get dimension or nesting level of element in list

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

`the_list = ['mob', 'rob', ['hix', ['lu', 'mu'], 'rix', 'mob']]`

How do I get the nesting level of an element in the list?
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for the_element in the_list:
    the_dimension = get_dimension_of_element(the_element)
    print(the_element, the_dimension)
```

which would output:

```
'mob', 1
'rob', 1
'hix', 2
'lu', 3
'mu', 3
'rix', 2
'mob', 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use recursion, because what you're doing depends on whether the element is a list or just a string.

```
def level_print(data, level=1):
    for elem in data:
        if isinstance(elem, (list, tuple)):
             level_print(elem, level + 1)
        else:
            print("{!r}, {}".format(elem, level))

level_print(the_list)
```

Here's a function that returns the resulting output.

```
def level_enumerate(data, level=1):
    result = []
    for elem in data:
        if isinstance(elem, (list, tuple)):
             result.extend(level_enumerate(elem, level + 1))
        else:
             result.append((elem, level))
    return result

print(level_enumerate(the_list))
```

Comment: works great.  thanks a lot.  i passed a third argument into the function, `new_list=[]` and then changed the print statement to `new_list.append((elem, level))` so I could capture the output.

Comment: @Ryan B. Jawad, glad the snippet helped. One thing about recursion though, is you probably want to hide the `level` parameter, so I probably would leave that at the end. You probably could collect the recursive output though.

Comment: I'm not very good with recursive functions, but for what I'm working on, the function you posted is great.  It turned about 300 lines of code into 16.  And it's a general solution; my solution was based on cases.